# Iterating over array to check whether strings ```includes``` another string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

using the `includes`method to check whether strings in an array include another string. Basically like a search function type of thing.

Heres what I have so far

```
this.findIngredient = function(ingredientName) {
          for (i=0; i < this.ingredients.length; i++) {
               if (this.ingredients[i].includes(ingredientName)) {
                     return true
                     break
                 } else {
                    return false
                   }
                }
            }
```

what im unsure about is why when the `this.ingredient` does hold a string that includes `ingredientName` it still outputs `false`.

For context this is the `this.ingredient` array

```
this.ingredients = ["500g plain flour", "1 tsp fine salt", "2 heaped tsp baking powder"]
```

Comment: You're unconditionally `return`ing on the first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the else block from within your loop should resolve the issue.

Explanation -

The else block is run when `this.ingredients[i].includes(ingredientName)` is `false`. And in your code, when the else block returns `false` which means your loop will not have the opportunity to check every element in the ingredients array since the function will stop execution when it sees a return statement.

Comment: if the array does not hold the ```ingredientName``` how would i add that else clause to return false

Comment: Make the following changes - no need to put break after a return statement as it breaks the loop automatically. Second, put `return false` outside the loop.